# How to get dynamic tab names and data using tabView in PrimeFaces 5.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to display tab names dynamically. Each of the tabs will then have its own list of data.
For e.g. If tab name is "Student", it will display a list of students when user clicks on "Student" tab. If "Teacher" tab is clicked, it will display a list of teachers.
I was referring PrimeFaces examples using below link.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml

I tried using Data Model and Ajax event examples, but I am unable to display desired data.  events do not work with Data Model.

I have tried below methods,

```
<p:tabView value="#{myBean.tabList}" var="tabItem">
    <p:tab title="#{tabItem.tabTitle}">
        <h:outputText value="#{tabItem.valueA}"/>

    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

If I use this method, data is dynamic, but not the way I want. My data is like Tab Name is a list and data for each tab is another list.

```
TabView tabView = new TabView();
Tab newTab = new Tab();            
newTab.setTitle("Tab Title");  

Tab newTab2 = new Tab();            
newTab2.setTitle("Tab Title2");     
tabView.getChildren().add(newTab2);
```

Can anyone help out?

**UPDATE**

I am now able to display dynamic data as required by creating PrimeFaces code from backing bean. TabView is inside a `<p:dialog>` box.

```
out1 = new SelectBooleanCheckbox();
out1.setValue(obj.isTabViewCheckBox());
out2 = new HtmlOutputLabel();
out2.setValue(obj.getTaskName());
```

I am facing new issue.. I am not able to get the SelectBooleanCheckbox value after the  is submitted.
XHTML Code:

```
<p:dialog header="#{BB.projNo}" widgetVar="addData" modal="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" styleClass="editProjects">
<h:panelGrid id="TaskAdd">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Tasks"/>
    </f:facet>
    <p:tabView id="tabView" binding="#{BB.tabView}">
    </p:tabView>
</h:panelGrid>
<p:commandButton id="saveBtn" action="#{BB.addTask}" value="Save"  style="align:center;" styleClass="buttonStyle" onstart="showLoadImg();" oncomplete="hideLoadImg();PF('addData').hide();add();" >
</p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
```

How to get the value of the selected items on  submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a way out to get checkbox value after the  is submitted.
Since I have 2 lists, one for tab names and another for tab data, i had to iterate over both the lists.

```
tabView.getChildren().get(index).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(indexTwo+1).getAttributes().get("value").toString();
```

I had to refer each child elements generated from managedBean which was initially used to generate the checkbox component .

Answer (score 1):

You can use jstl forEach tag

```
<p:tabView id="myTabView">
    <c:forEach var="tab" items="#{myBean.tabs}">
                    <p:tab title="#{tab.title}">
                        <ui:include src="#{tab.url}" />
                    </p:tab>
                </c:forEach>
</p:tabView>
```

**In your myBean**
Build the list to iterate

```
List<MyTabObject> tabs = new ArrayList<MyTabObject>();
tabs.add(new MyTabObject("Tab Title", "/path/to/contentFile.xhtml"));
```

**MyTabObject**

```
    public class MyTabObject {
        private String title;
        private String url;

        public MyTabObject() {

        }

        public MyTabObject(String title, String url) {
            this.title = title;
            this.url = url;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the `value` attribute of `<p:tabView>` to dynamically generate tabs.

```
<p:tabView
   id="mytabView"
   value="#{bean.objectList}"
   var="item">

   <p:tab title="#{item.name}">
   ...content...
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: how to bind another list inside <p:tab title="#{item.name}"></p:tab>?